# Change Google App Script to select specific sheet and clear it before continuing script

Tags: database, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've worked out a script to gather data from a remote MS SQL db and populate a Google Sheet.  I need some help further refining the code to select a specific sheet and clear the sheet before continuing the script so that each time the script runs the sheet has the latest data from the db table.

Here is the script.

```
function database_connection() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;" + "databaseName=mydbname;user=mydbusername;password=mypassword;");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(500);
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('select * from table_name');

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a sheet you can use [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName%28String%29) or [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets%28%29) as per your requirement.

To clear the all the cells in a sheet, use the [clear](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear%28%29) method of class `Range`.

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("sheetName");
sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clear()
```

Googling will definitely help...

**Edit**

[getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange%28%29) can also be used to clear all the ranges (see below)

This is how you can use bulk insert

```
function database_connection() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;" + "databaseName=mydbname;user=mydbusername;password=mypassword;");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(500);
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('select * from table_name');

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByname("sheetName")
  sheet.getDataRange().clear();
  var data = [], rowData;
  var numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); // <- not sure about this, basically i want to capture number of columns
  while (rs.next()) {
    rowData = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowData.push(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    data.push(rowData);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, numCols).setValues(data); // <- single operation to insert
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Also I would suggest you to not enter the values one by one using setValue. When you do this, you are making inserts for each cell.Inserting the data in bulk is really fast. Store the values in an array of arrays and use setValues

Comment: Konstant will you help me with that syntax as well?  Thanks for showing me how to grab the name and clear the sheet, it worked perfectly.  I appreciate your passing the knowledge along.

Comment: @DaveLalande: I will edit my answer to include the bulk insert syntax